# Laravel unique mobile number in the request

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with editing mobile staff in the request function, I don't have a staff id on my page, I use the same page for editing staff mobile (nav nav-tabs) and (tab-pane)
in my view Html code below

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a @click="getContant($event)" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#EditStaff" 
        id="Donuts_section_HTML" style="border-radius: 0;">
   <div class="store-report">
     {{ __('messages.edit staff') }}
   </div>
    </a>
</li>

<div id="EditStaff" class="container tab-pane fade pl-0 pr-0"><br>
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <form method="POST" action="{{ action('Admin\StaffController@editStaffDone') }}" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="{{-- return validform() --}}">
       @csrf     
       <div class="form-group">
         <div class="form-row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
           <select name="EditStaffSelect" id="EditStaffSelect" class="form-control placeholder 
             radiusb arabic-family">
             <option value="0">{{ __('messages.Select Staff') }}</option>
             @if($staff != "Empty Staff")
                @foreach ($staff as $item)
                 <option value="{{ $item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
             @else
               <option value='0'> __('messages.Empty Staff')</option>
             @endif
         </select>
       </div>
       <div style="width: fit-content;">
          @error('EditStaffSelect')
            <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-danger text-left pt-3"><img src="{{ 
             url('/images/warning.png') }}"> <strong>{{ $message }}</strong></small>
          @enderror
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="form-row">
     <label for="EditstaffMobileNumber" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-left font-weight- 
       normal">{{ __('messages.Mobile Number') }}</label>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="text" name="EditstaffMobileNumber" id="EditstaffMobileNumber" class="form-control placeholder" value="{{ old('staffMobileNumber') }}" onpaste="return false" placeholder="{{ __('messages.Mobile Number') }}">
      </div>
     <div style="width: fit-content;">
       @error('EditstaffMobileNumber')
        <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-danger text-left pt-3"><img src="{{ 
          url('/images/warning.png') }}"> <strong>{{ $message }}</strong></small>
       @enderror
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <button type="submit" id="submit_AddStaff" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm radius mt-2 shadow">{{ 
     __('messages.Submit')}}</button>
    <a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-1 mt-2 radius shadow">{{ 
     __('messages.back') }}</a>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
@if(Session::has('success_insert'))
   <div class="col-md-5 alert alert-success alert-dismissible font-weight-bold text-left mt-2 ml-0 
    radius text-capitalize" role="alert">
      {{ Session::get('success_insert') }}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
  </div>

@endif
</div>
</div>
```

```
public function editStaff(Request $request)
{
    $staff_id = $request->get('staff_id');
    $purpose = $request->get('purpose');
    $staffNumber = Staff::where('id', '=', $staff_id)->pluck('mobile')->first();

    return $staffNumber;
}

public function editStaffDone(EditStaff $request)
{
    Staff::where('id', '=', $request->EditStaffSelect)->update([
        'mobile' => $request->EditstaffMobileNumber,
    ]);

    return redirect()->back()->with(['success_insert' => __('messages.success update')]);
}
```

How can I add a unique mobile number without `staff_id` on my page?
If I add `unique:Staffs,mobile,` in the rules section I get ann errors. If I save the post if i don't change the mobile number.

Comment: Can you put Controller code?

Comment: public function editStaffDone(EditStaff $request)
    {
        //dd($request->EditStaffSelect . ' ' . $request->EditstaffMobileNumber);
        Staff::where('id', '=', $request->EditStaffSelect)
            ->update([
                'mobile'  => $request->EditstaffMobileNumber
            ]);

        return redirect()->back()->with(['success_insert' => __('messages.success update')]);

Comment: i use an ajax to get the mobile like :     public function editStaff(Request $request)
    {
        $staff_id = $request->get('staff_id');
        $purpose     = $request->get('purpose');
        //dd($staff_id . ' ' . $purpose);
        $staffNumber = Staff::where('id', '=', $staff_id)->pluck('mobile')->first();
        return $staffNumber;
    }

Comment: Update the question with the code and description

Comment: ```    public function editStaff(Request $request)
    {
        $staff_id = $request->get('staff_id');
        $purpose     = $request->get('purpose');
        //dd($staff_id . ' ' . $purpose);
        $staffNumber = Staff::where('id', '=', $staff_id)->pluck('mobile')->first();
        return $staffNumber;
    }```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the current `mobile number` to the rule so that Laravel can ignore comparing with the current mobile number as:

```
unique:Staffs,mobile,' . $request->mobile;
```

Read more about that: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation, read the `Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID` section.

Comment: ErrorException
Undefined variable: request

Comment: Show the part where you have declared the rules

Comment: i have a request which is Separated of controller